# In R, command works on the variable, rather than the object the variable adresses. How can I fix this?

Tags: r, variables, command, data-manipulation

I am stuck with a rather stupid issue. I run a loop where numbers are appended to a string to address various columns of a data frame. These column names are then stored in a variable. Then, I run a command on this variable. However, the command is run on the name of what the variable contains, rather than the object represented by the name.

I have previously tried `as.character`, `deparse`, `as.array` etc.

```
library(qdap)

for (q in 1:9)
{
  lolz <- freq_terms(paste("df$col_0", q , sep = ""))
  assign (paste("freq", q, sep = ""), lolz)
```

Instead of the the command `freq_terms` being applied to the `q`th column of `df` and being stored in `freq'q'`, the command is applied to the string `df$col_01`

An example of the data

```
col_01  col_02  col_03 col_04
 hey    no       yes   ok
  Yo    yes       ok   NA
  no    hey       NA   ok
```

The error I receive is

> Error in names(y) <- c("WORD", "FREQ") : 
>       'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I would try `freq_terms(df[[paste0("col_0", q)]])`

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work... this part df[[paste0("col_0", q)]] returns null.

Comment: In that case we will likely need to see (at least a subset of) your data to help, which you can provide by editing your question to include the output of `dput(head(df))` -- the `[[` method I demonstrated should usually work. as an example, try `df_ex <- data.frame(col_01 = 1, col_02 = 2); df_ex[[paste0("col_0", 1)]]`

Comment: So, I tried `df[,paste0("col_0", q, sep="")]` which solves the first problem... however, the function `freq_terms` doesn't work... I'll add the data

Answer (score 0):

I add this "answer" just to demonstrate that I cannot reproduce your problem with the information given. When I run

```
library(qdap)

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
col_01  col_02  col_03 col_04
 hey    no       yes   ok
  Yo    yes       ok   NA
  no    hey       NA   ok")

freq_terms(df[[paste0("col_0", 1)]])
```

I get as output

```
  WORD FREQ
1 hey     1
2 no      1
3 yo      1
```

That is why I suggest adding a subset of your data to your question by copying the output of `dput(head(df))` rather than how you did -- `dput()` will give us more information about the object `df`, which could be causing your problems. You may also want to add the output of `sessionInfo()` -- could be informative.

Comment: I reran the code after rebooting both myself and the pc. It works. You have my eternal gratitude! (p.s. The data is sensitive - I completely understand the requirement for it to help understand the problem better, but unfortunately I am not at the liberty to share.) Thanks again!